# Behaviour of floating point precision for division

Tags: javascript, floating-point

While working with various floating point number solutions I have been logging the values to compare the outputs. e.g.

```
console.log(3 * 0.1) //0.30000000000000004
console.log(3 * 0.2) //0.6000000000000001
console.log(3 * 0.0001) //0.00030000000000000003
console.log(0.07 * 0.9) //0.06300000000000001
```

I was curious to see the behavior on the same problem for division and noticed that the answer was logging correctly;

```
console.log(3 / (1 / 0.1)) //0.3
console.log(3 / (1 / 0.2)) //0.6
console.log(3 / (1 / 0.0001)) //0.0003
console.log(0.07 / (1 / 0.9)) //0.063
```

What is happening differently here for division vs multiplication? All the examples of undesired floating point behaviour have been with multiplication, does it also apply to division? can someone show me a basic example of division breaking for decimal numbers?

**Disclaimer:** I am aware that floating point numbers are decimal wise innacurate, and that there are many working solutions to multiply floating point numbers that are generally accepted. Please do not post a solution to floating point multiplication, or a link to another SO answer that doesn't directly answer my question above, as I have been browsing many related SO answers already.

Comment: @Paulpro, _"the rational number 0.1, which is 1/10, can be written exactly as `0.1` in decimal"_ did make me feel so...

Comment: Example of division "breaking": try `3 / (1 / 0.00001)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks! I suppose all I need now is a better understanding of floating point arithmatic to understand why these differences would occur.